# sync: negative WaitGroup counter

Tags: go, slice, waitgroup

Who can tell me why the panic occurs. The background of this demo is to verify the behavior of slice cocurrent write, but when I run the demo, panic occurs occasionally (not always). So Why?

The code:

```
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
                // when capacity > 2, panic disappear
        b := make([]int, 2, 2) 
        b[0], b[1] = 0, 1

        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            b = append(b, 3)
            wg.Done()
        }()
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            b = append(b, 4)
            wg.Done()
        }()
        wg.Wait()
    }

}
```

Errors:

```
panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter

goroutine 12821 [running]:
sync.(*WaitGroup).Add(0x0?, 0xc0000f4ba0?)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:83 +0xda
sync.(*WaitGroup).Done(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:108
main.main.func1()
        /Users/liushi/Projects/go/golang-demo/main.go:54 +0x97
created by main.main
        /Users/liushi/Projects/go/golang-demo/main.go:48 +0x11f

Process finished with the exit code 2
```

When the capacity of b more than 2, panic disappears.

Comment: There is a synchronisation bug in your program because, as Maria correctly pointed out [in her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77589595/2541573), you're appending to a slice from two goroutines without synchronisation. However, I don't think the panic you observed could have been triggered by the program shown in your question. You must not be telling us everything.

Comment: @jub0bs the code OP gave is complete, I was able to reproduce the panic they mentioned

Comment: @jub0bs I've duplicated this with the provided code (go 1.21.4 windows/amd64). Could not duplicate after adding a Mutex.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Interesting! I cannot reproduce the issue on the Playground. What OS/architecture combination were you able to reproduce it on?

Comment: @Brits Thanks for the additional details. Like Maria, I find this panic surprising.

Comment: @jub0bs I reproduced on a MacBook Pro with Intel

Comment: I guess the following comment from [The Go Memory Model](https://go.dev/ref/mem#restrictions) applies "When the values depend on the consistency of internal (pointer, length) or (pointer, type) pairs, as can be the case for interface values, maps, slices, and strings in most Go implementations, such races can in turn lead to arbitrary memory corruption."

Comment: @Brits Seems like a reasonable explanation! I have checked the address of `wg` is identical when panic occurs.

Answer (score 5):

As an FYI: `b` is a slice. Slices have fixed size arrays backing them. In your case, `b` has two elements and it's already full. So when you try to `append`, Go has to do a bit more work before appending, it has to copy all elements into a new backing array. If you change the initial capacity to `3`, the first time you call `append` will execute quickly.

The problem with your code is that you have a data race on the `b` variable. This is easy to verify if you run with `go test -race .` To fix this, you could use a mutex to control concurrent access to `b`.

Now, I don't know exactly *why* it's panicking on `wg.Add(1)`, but since you currently are corrupting memory, first fix that and then see if you get panics. I think you shouldn't get any because the `WaitGroup` portion looks fine to me.

Comment: I can’t agree more with the conclusion that the panic occurs because of the data race and using mutex can fix the panic.      

But, this panic doubts me the correct way to use `WaitGroup`.

Comment: @Derrick why? The way you did it looks correct. https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups

Comment: Thanks! Now, I'm pretty sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maria's explanation that there's a data race for `b` is correct. Here's the right way to implement this with a mutex:

```golang
package main

import "sync"

func main() {
  mut := sync.Mutex{}
  for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
    // when capacity > 2, panic disappear
    b := make([]int, 2, 2)
    b[0], b[1] = 0, 1

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
      mut.Lock()
      b = append(b, 3)
      mut.Unlock()
      wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
      mut.Lock()
      b = append(b, 4)
      mut.Unlock()
      wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
  }

}
```

Another clue that this may be due to memory corruption is the fact that when the capacity is increased the panic disappears. Currently, with capacity 2, the Go runtime is forced to double the underlying array's size before it appends the value 3, and the data race could mean that this increase interferes with where memory for `wg` is stored.